# Add Checkbox to header of ng-grid. At time maximum 2 checkbox selected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, ng-grid

[Diseregard checkbox in row in below picuter but]
I want to have checkbox besides four header i.e. Maths, Physic, Chemistry and Biology. I  also want to this checkbox behave similiar to redio button but slight differently. I mean at a time maximum 2 checkbox can be selected. For example.

1. I select Math Checkbox
2. I select Physics Checkbox
3. Now i Select Chemistry Checkbox. Math Checkbox should be unselected.

[image]

Comment: I cannot write the whole methods for you, but in short you need to create a method in your controller which is run when you select any of you checkboxes (there is for instance ng-click and ng-change events, try which one fits your needs the best), then you need to track (means, stored in variables) what was selected and unselect the rest of them. Thank you

Comment: And how to add checkboxes in column?

Comment: With a custom HeaderCellTemplate. https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating But what are these checkboxes intended to do?